# Extending ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

I have implemented a `ThreadPoolExecutor` that will run a `Consumer<T>` only on elements not already consumed. This code uses Java 8.

The background behind this is that I scan a directory every x time units for which files are present, I must maintain a 100% accuracy on finding files and other mechanisms such as *JNotify* or a simple plain `WatcherService` do not achieve that.

```
public class SingleExecutionThreadPoolExecutor<E> extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    private final Consumer<E> consumer;
    private final List<E> elementsInProcess = new ArrayList<>();

    public SingleExecutionThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, Consumer<E> consumer) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public SingleExecutionThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, Consumer<E> consumer, RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, handler);
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public SingleExecutionThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, Consumer<E> consumer, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory);
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public SingleExecutionThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, Consumer<E> consumer, ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public void execute(E element) {
        if (!elementsInProcess.contains(element)) {
            super.execute(() -> consumer.accept(element));
            elementsInProcess.add(element);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void execute(Runnable command) { }
}
```

It is called using the following classes and snippets:

```
public final class UniqueTimePath {
    private final Path path;
    private final FileTime fileTime;

    public UniqueTimePath(final Path path) {
        this.path = path;
        try {
            this.fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public FileTime getFileTime() {
        return fileTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final UniqueTimePath other = (UniqueTimePath) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.path, other.path)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.fileTime, other.fileTime)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + path + ", " + fileTime + "}";
    }
}
```

---

```
private SingleExecutionThreadPoolExecutor<UniqueTimePath> executor;
//...
executor = new SingleExecutionThreadPoolExecutor<>(threadCount, threadCount, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(), fileConsumer);
//...
Files.list(directory)
        .map(UniqueTimePath::new)
        .forEach(executor::execute);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## .equals

The last part of your `.equals` implementation can be simplified to:

```
return Objects.equals(this.path, other.path) && Objects.equals(this.fileTime, other.fileTime);
```

## HashCode

```
int hash = 3;
return hash;
```

Do I even have to comment anything about what I think about this implementation? You use Objects.equals above, you can use `Objects.hashCode(this.path, this.fileTime);` here. It is preferred if `hashCode` and `equals` use the same fields for their operations.

## Set or List?

Whenever you use a `List` in a program, ask yourself the question: Does the order of the elements matter?

In this case, they don't. Use the `Set` interface and create as `HashSet` for your `elementsInProcess` variable.

```
private final Set<E> elementsInProcess = new HashSet<>();
```

When using a Set, it is **extra important** that the elements in the set has properly implemented `hashCode` and `equals`! (Or are using the default implementations inherited from the `Object` class)

## Cleanup

I suggest you override the `shutdown` methods of a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to clear the `elementsInProcess` collection.

## `execute(Runnable command)`

Please throw a `UnsupportedOperationException` or similar in this method:

```
public void execute(Runnable command) { }
```

**Edit:** Scratch that. I think palacsint is absolutely right. By doing nothing here, you're breaking the contract of the `Executor` interface (which you implement, whether you know it or not - by extending an ExecutorService). The Javadoc for the [execute(Runnable command)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method says:

> Executes the given command at some time in the future.

As it currently stands, you are not doing that and have no real ability of doing so in that method. This fact is an indication that you should not use `extends ThreadPoolExecutor` and instead use a `private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;`, and therefore using composition over inheritance.

## Concurrency

*If* two threads would call `execute` at the same time, there is a concurrency issue on `elementsInProcess`. You need to synchronize on something there, for minimal blocking I suggest you do something like this:

```
synchronize (lock) {
    if (elementsInProcess.contains(element)) {
        return;
    }
    elementsInProcess.add(element);
}
super.execute(() -> consumer.accept(element));
```

Where `lock` is a `private final Object lock = new Object();`

Or, you could utilize the fact that the `.add` method of a set actually returns a boolean indicating if the add was successful and use a `Collections.synchronizedSet`.

```
if (!elementsInProcess.add(element)) {
    return;
}
super.execute(() -> consumer.accept(element));
```

It is important when using a synchronized Set that you only do one method call here, as there could otherwise be a gap between `.contains` and `.add` which would again cause concurrency issues between threads.

Answer (score 10):

1. I would definitely use composition here instead of inheritance. It would eliminate the following ugly (and [smelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)) code too:

   > ```
   > @Override
   > @Deprecated
   > public void execute(Runnable command) { }
   > ```

   The internals of `ThreadPoolExecutor` could be changed by JDK developers, so in a future release `submit()` methods might not call the overridden empty `execute()` method any more or they could provide a new public `execute` method which bypass your `execute()`.

   See also: *Effective Java, Second Edition*, *Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*
2. The code should check that the `consumer` is `null` in the constructors and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or `NullPointerException` right there.
   If it remains `null` you'll get an exception later in the `execute` method anyway. Throwing an exception immediately helps debugging a lot since you get a stacktrace with the frames of the erroneous client, not just a `NullPointerException` later, probably from another thread. (*The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt and David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*.)
3. Most developers would expect that [submitting jobs from different threads is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1702386/843804), so I'd use a properly synchronized `elementsInProcess` list instead of `ArrayList` to meet this expectation.
4. The following will lead to [poor performance if you use your objects in a `HashMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579032/843804):

   > ```
   > @Override
   > public int hashCode() {
   >     int hash = 3;
   >     return hash;
   > }
   > ```

   Consider implementing a proper `hashCode`.

Comment: Is composition here worth the fact that you need to add delegating methods for **all** functionality of `ThreadPoolExecutor`?

Comment: @skiwi: Eclipse can generate those methods for you, so it is not too much work but you will have a lot more control, better API and less bugs in the long run. The referred Effective Java item mentions the `Properties` class as famous bad example, read that chapter if you can. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11344295/843804)

Comment: However if normal (non-default) methods get added to `ThreadPoolExecutor`, then clients of my code will not have access to those methods, that is also a concern.

Comment: @skiwi: Later you can make those available to your clients with a new release of your code but removing a method from a public API is much harder since it could break existing clients.

Comment: If new methods are added, you should consider which must be available from your class. Allowing a helper class to dictate your class's API without your knowledge or ability to vet the changes is a recipe for disaster, i.e. random bugs.

Comment: +1 to composition over inheritance for this one.  I'm not usually a strong advocate for this principle, but I *am* a strong advocate for the *Liskov Substitution Principle* (see http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html), which your code violates.  Using composition and not exposing the parts of the API that you prevent from operating as their contract specifies would be the best approach here. (Yes, it's also violated by several parts of the core Java library, but that is the most serious design error in Java to my mind.)

Comment: @skiwi Do you really need to expose *all* the methods of a `ThreadPoolExecutor`?  Your example of use only uses a small handful of them, so why not only expose those?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @SimonAndréForsberg and @palacsint's answers, I have however reconsidered the design and noticed that I do not even want to really use composition for the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

I have refactored the code to the class below, where the following assumptions hold:

- The `Consumer<T>` is already known.
- The `Executor` has already been instantiated, in this case an instantiation of a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
public class SingleExecutionExecutorBridge<T> implements Consumer<T> {
    private final Consumer<T> consumer;
    private final Executor executor;

    private final Set<T> elementsInProcess = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());

    public SingleExecutionExecutorBridge(final Consumer<T> consumer, final Executor executor) {
        this.consumer = Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
        this.executor = Objects.requireNonNull(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(final T element) {
        if (!elementsInProcess.add(element)) {
            return;
        }
        executor.execute(() -> consumer.accept(element));
    }
}
```

With this approach everything is decoupled nicely, and the following code snippets are now relevant:

```
private final SingleExecutionExecutorBridge<UniqueTimePath> singleExecutionExecutorBridge;
private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

//...

public BaseChecker(final Path directory, final Consumer<UniqueTimePath> fileConsumer, final Path configFile) {
    this.directory = Objects.requireNonNull(directory);
    this.configFile = Objects.requireNonNull(configFile);
    this.subClass = this.getClass();
    this.singleExecutionExecutorBridge = new SingleExecutionExecutorBridge<>(Objects.requireNonNull(fileConsumer), executor);
}

//...

executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadCount, threadCount, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());

//...

Files.list(directory)
        .map(UniqueTimePath::new)
        .forEach(singleExecutionExecutorBridge::accept);
```

Comment: Nice, well done. You might want to add `Objects.requireNonNull` in your constructor for `SingleExecutionExecutorBridge` though

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Yes, yes I do, I'll edit the post to include them.

Comment: I have to say that what you did here is composition :-). Unfortunately I didn't have time earlier to show a complete example like this one but I'm glad that you write it. Furthermore, I've found the constructor injection really easy to test with mocked executors. So it's much better than creating a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` inside the class could be.